# Chances of winning if only a certain amount of people can participate

Tags: stochastic-processes, percentages

So we got 2 million (2_000_000) cornflakes boxes. Hidden in 6 of those cornflakes boxes is a gold nugget.

Due to a wrong printing, 500_000 cornflakes boxes don't get into the market.
So there are 1_500_000 cornflakes boxes available to buy.

What are the chances of giving each buyer a gold nugget. (A buyer can buy a SINGLE cornflakes box). Is it even possible to calculate a percentage out of these informations?

The tutor suggets something like: "NOT WORKING" or "X% to Y% to sell ALL 6 goldnuggets)

I don't think it's possible because you don't actually know how many boxes containing goldnuggets are available to buy. (Maybe 6 gold nuggets, maybe 0).

Can you guys give me a clue how I should continue? Or even give me the right mathematical way of solving this issue?

I'm not a native speaker therefore I think the title might be misleading. I'm gonna change it if someone suggets something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably supposed to assume that the chance of a misprinted box holding a nugget is the same as the chance of a properly printed box holding a nugget.  In that case the chance of a given box holding a nugget is still $6$ in $2,000,000$.  When you buy a box, you don't know whether the other half million were sold or destroyed, so you can ignore it.

It is true that if there is a correlation between misprinting and having a nugget the chance will change.  As we are not given that information, we assume the two conditions are independent.

Comment: Let's say only 10_000 people buy the cornflakes boxes. What's the chance of selling all 6 nuggets to those people? (2 million boxes, everything properly printed) :o

Comment: It would be $\frac {10,000*9999*9998*9997*9996*9995}{2,000,000*\dots*1,999,995}$, very close to $\left(\frac {10,000}{2,000,000}\right)^6=\frac 1{200^6}$